# get user id from username or email without logging in

Tags: users, 8

I want to get the user id and role before the user is logged in.  If i have the email or username, what function can I use with D8 to get the user id ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can load the user with `loadByProperties()`:

```
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')
  ->loadByProperties(['mail' => $mail]);
$user = reset($users);
if ($user) {
  $uid = $user->id();
  $rids = $user->getRoles();
}
```

Comment: thanks what about the user name?

Comment: also the syntax is wrong on this, the mail is not closed with a ] and the double arrow shouldnt be there.  can you give me the right syntax please?

Comment: The syntax should be OK. The properties are in an array. You can place any field in this array. For the username: `['name' => $name]` or both at the same time: `['name' => $name, 'mail' => $mail]`

Answer (score 5):

Drupal 8 now also has these specific functions:

**user_load_by_name()**

```
$user = user_load_by_name('some user');
$uid = $user->id();
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_name/8.9.x

**user_load_by_mail()**

```
$user = user_load_by_mail('email@example.com');
$uid = $user->id();
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/8.9.x