# Get user role by user field

Tags: users

how can I access to my user role thanks to my user custom field ?

I have an user field called "custField" and it's value (example : 123456). I need to check all users that have "123456" as value.

Then, I need to check if this user as the role "director".

But I don't know how to access role thanks to another field.

EDIT :

See this loop :

```
foreach($retraitDoublons as $valUnique){
  $users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')
    ->loadByProperties(['field_custVal' => $valUnique]);
  $user = reset($users);
  $user_has_role = $user && $user->hasRole('directeur_cr_');

  dump($user);
  dump($user_has_role);

  echo $valUnique . "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215660/get-user-id-from-username-or-email-without-logging-in):

I have an user field called "custField" and it's value (example : 123456). I need to check all users that have "123456" as value:

```
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_custField' => '123456']);
```

Then, I need to check if this user:

```
$user = reset($users);
```

has the role "director":

```
$user_has_role = $user && $user->hasRole('director');
```

Comment: This will work with the no current user (I forgot this part, I need this for not current user)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow, all users can't be a current user. I've inserted your question step-by-step.

Comment: See my updated answer please. Your code seems to work (because $user_has_role is returning true), but my loop is doing this only one time, even if there's several account related to this value.

Comment: Then you need to loop over $users. This is a PHP question and the code depends on what you want to do with the result.

Comment: According to your code, what should I change ?