# Associate Every Displayed User Name With Corresponding users.data Table Row

Tags: 8, users

**Updated:**

I would like data from the `users.data` table displayed with every "User Name" however it is displayed.

As an example, I have this in `hook_preprocess_page_title()`:

```
function hook_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.user.canonical') {

    $gUD = \Drupal::service('user.data');
    $routeUID = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('user');
    $gudValue = $gUD->get('module', $routeUID, 'name');

    if ($gudValue = $moduleValue)) {
      kpr('Success!');
    }

  }

}
```

The route `entity.user.canonical` allows me to reference the viewed user, and so I can use `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('user')` to get the non-current user ID. (it's not the route that counts, but my ability to reference the `users.data` table for the displayed user)

And this in `hook_preprocess_username()`:

```
function hook_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $gUD = getUsersData();
  $gudValue = $gUD->get('module', $variables['uid'], 'name');
}
```

So what I am looking for is something like:

```
hook_preprocess_HOOK() {
  $UID = // From displayed user name.
  \Drupal::service('user.data')->get('module', $UID, 'name');
}
```

for each displayed user name.

The problem here: [get user id from username or email without logging in](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215660/get-user-id-from-username-or-email-without-logging-in), is that I don't know, and cannot manually enter the username value.

---

A couple of examples where the username is displayed on a page without using the `username` field:

1. Views field Name (not linked to user, uses `views field` base)
2. User type entity reference field (format display `label`, uses `field` base)

`hook_preprocess_page_title()` and `hook_preprocess_username()` are pretty straight-forward. And I believe I know where/when this template/hook will be used, but I am still having trouble defining a couple of other instances, and determining the best hook to alter the output as needed.

Comment: `loadByProperties()` queries the entire user table. Why should it be restricted to current user values?

Comment: While trying to get the value of `username` from a preprocess function, without a route parameter of `.user.`, I have not found a way to set that value to something other than the current user.

Comment: I might have had a little progress, and it may better define what I'm asking. Once I set the `format` option of the user entity reference field to `Author`, instead of `label` on my content type, and now actually renders out the username field value, `hook_preprocess_username(&$variables)` does return `$variables['name']` relative to the referenced user, not the current user. My error? Maybe, but now I'm unsure about `label format display.

Comment: The label display is generic to all entities, it simply prints out what is defined as label for the entity, title for a node, or username for a user. When you render the user you have the normal theming options including preprocess hooks.

Comment: It's not clear for which pages you are interested to get the user information. There are many pages for which the route name is not *entity.user.canonical*. Some of them could be user pages, some of them are for entities with a user entity reference field, and some of them aren't related to a user account in any way.

Comment: Just to make an example, if you are using `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` inside `hook_preprocess_page_title()` when the user is visiting /user/1/edit, the route name would not be *entity.user.canonical*, but the page is still about a user account; it's actually the edit form for the user #1, but still there is a user account associated to that page.

Comment: I've added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should start with what you don't want.

`Drupal::currentUser()->id()` will retrieve the current user's UID. From there, you can use the `UserStorage::loadByProperties()` method you referenced to pull the UID by user name. The last step is add code to check `Drupal::currentUser()->id()` doesn't match the UID found from `UserStorage::loadByProperties()`

Comment: What it's not clear from the question is for which pages the OP is trying to access the user information. There are many pages for which `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` doesn't return `'entity.user.canonical'`. If the page is associated to a user account, then it's quite easy to get information about that user. Differently, there are many users who aren't the currently logged-in user. `UserStorage::loadByProperties()` doesn't allow to load all the users for which the user ID is not a given one.

Comment: I think in most cases this would have been the correct answer, but @kiamlaluno is right about the UserStorage::loadByProperties() in my case. My question is how to get that value in the context of the user shown/listed. I did not ask the question very well as the issue may be a little different.